# PostgreSQL left join query with optional input arguments

Tags: postgresql

I have a database schema where I have three tables A, B and C where the primary key id of A is the foreign key for B and C. I am given a condition where I am supposed to query a column of A given some values of column B and C. It is also possible that B and C column inputs can be null.

So to summarize,

```
   A has two fields id and name
   B has two fields id and age 
   C has two fields id and gender
```

I am trying to design a query which would do the following

```
`select * from A 
Left join B on B.id = A.id and b.age = $1 
Left join C on C.id = A.id and c.gender = $2;`
```

Here $1 and $2 are coming from an external program in Rust and can be null. The problem is even if I pass valid inputs to these queries, the filtering results are incorrect.

Is there a simpler way to execute this query such that the Join 1 only occurs when $1 is not null and Join 2 only occurs when $2 is not null.

```
`select * from A 
Left join B on B.id = A.id and b.age = $1 
Left join C on C.id = A.id and c.gender = $2;`
```

I tried the above query but the results are not as expected.

Comment: `and b.age = $1` --> `and b.age = $1 or $1 is null` ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output for given parameters.

Comment: "*a query which would do the following*" - please describe in words or with examples what you want to get. If the query doesn't do what you want, how can we know what you actually want if you only post the non-working query?

Answer (score 0):

By "Join 1 only occurs when $1 is not null and Join 2 only occurs when $2 is not null," I assume that the desired behavior is to filter the results by age or gender only when the associated argument is non-NULL. I infer from the use of `LEFT JOIN` that not every row in table A is required to have a corresponding row in table B or table C, thus either age or gender might be unknown. Should the results only include rows that are known to match supplied parameters, or should rows with unknown ages or genders also be included? Both cases are addressed below.

The following query returns all rows that are known to match provided arguments:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.age, C.gender
  FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
    LEFT JOIN C ON C.id = A.id
  WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR B.age = $1)
    AND ($2 IS NULL OR C.gender = $2)
```

If the results should include unknown ages or genders along with known matches, then this query can be used:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.age, C.gender
  FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
    LEFT JOIN C ON C.id = A.id
  WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR B.age = $1 OR B.age IS NULL)
    AND ($2 IS NULL OR C.gender = $2 OR C.gender IS NULL)
```

Comment: That `COALESCE` is hard to understand imo. Either spell it out to `($1 IS NULL OR B.age IS NULL OR B.age = $1)`, or use `COALESCE(B.age = $1, TRUE)` (or even `(B.age = $1) IS NOT FALSE`)

Comment: @Bergi, I've edited my answer to use the spelled out expression instead of `COALESCE(B.age, $1) = $1`. The spelled out version probably imposes a lower cognitive load and more directly expresses the difference between the two queries. I think my original `COALESCE` is no more difficult to understand than any of the other alternatives you presented, and it is a common SQL idiom.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen `COALESCE(x, $1) = $1` from time to time, but I think when combining it with `$1 IS NULL` then it gets unnecessarily complicated.